# Django forms error: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite, django-forms

I am trying to create a website with two dropdown menus: Department and Course Number. The data for the dropdown menus comes from the "courses" table of my SQL database. Right now my website initializes properly and shows the correct options in the dropdown menu. However, when the user selects an option within the dropdown menu and submits their choice, Django throws a "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." error. I suspect that the output of my form isn't in the right format, so the selection can't be found in my database, but I've read many other SO questions with the same issue and still have gotten nowhere. Any help is appreciated.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Dept(models.Model):
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column = 'dept')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'courses'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dept

class Course_num(models.Model):
    course_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column = 'course_number')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'courses'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_num
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class CourseForm(forms.Form):
    dept = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Dept.objects.values_list('dept', flat = True).distinct().\
            order_by('dept').exclude(dept__isnull=True),
        required=False,
        empty_label="No preference",
        label=u"Department")

    course_num = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Course_num.objects.all().\
            order_by('course_num').values_list('course_num', flat = True).\
            distinct().exclude(course_num__isnull=True),
        required=False,
        empty_label="No preference",
        label=u"Course Number")
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    res = None
    form_CourseForm = CourseForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form_CourseForm = CourseForm(request.GET)
        args = {}
            if form_CourseForm.is_valid():
            dept = form_CourseForm.cleaned_data['dept']
            if dept:
                args['dept'] = dept
            course_num = form_CourseForm.cleaned_data['course_num']
            if course_num:
                args['course_num'] = course_num
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your queryset and try

```
class CourseForm(forms.Form):
    dept = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Dept.objects.distinct().
        order_by('dept').exclude(dept__isnull=True),
        required=False,
        empty_label="No preference",
        label=u"Department")

    course_num = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Course_num.objects.distinct().
        order_by('course_num').exclude(course_num__isnull=True),
        required=False,
        empty_label="No preference",
        label=u"Course Number")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it! However, after fixing this issue I'm now facing another issue detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125925/django-form-not-saving-inputs-refreshes-upon-submission. I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at it as well