# Django form not saving inputs- refreshes upon submission

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a website with two dropdown menus: Department and Course Number. The data for the dropdown menus comes from the "courses" table of my SQL database. Right now my website initializes properly and shows the correct options in the dropdown menus. However, when the user selects an option within the dropdown menus and submits their choices, the website reloads as a blank slate so their selections are not being saved or processed. The error lies somewhere in the CourseForm form because I have another form (Working_Form) that is created in a different way but works perfectly. What is wrong with CourseForm/its associated models?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Dept(models.Model):
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column = 'dept')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'courses'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dept

class Course_num(models.Model):
    course_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column = 'course_number')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'courses'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_num
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget
from .models import Dept, Course_num

class CourseForm(forms.Form):
    dept = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Dept.objects.distinct().\
            order_by('dept').exclude(dept__isnull=True),
        required=False,
        empty_label="No preference",
        label=u"Department")

    course_num = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Course_num.objects.distinct().\
            order_by('course_num').exclude(course_num__isnull=True),
        required=False,
        empty_label="No preference",
        label=u"Course Number")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from .models import Dept, Course_num
from .forms import CourseForm 
...
class Working_Form(forms.Form):
    working_info = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WORKING_DATA_LIST, required=False)
    show_args = forms.BooleanField(label='Show args_to_ui',
                               required=False)

def home(request):
    context = {}
    res = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_CourseForm = CourseForm(request.POST)
        working_info = Working_Form(request.POST)
        args = {}
        if form_CourseForm.is_valid():
            data = form_CourseForm.cleaned_data
            if data['dept']:
                args['dept'] = data['dept']
            if data['course_num']:
                args['course_num'] = data['course_num']
        if working_info.is_valid():
            ...
            if working_info.is_valid.cleaned_data['show_args']:
                context['args'] = 'args_to_ui = ' + json.dumps(args, indent=2)

        if ('dept' in args) == ('course_num' in args): 
            try:
                results = process_inputs(args)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception caught')
        else:
            context['err'] = forms.ValidationError("Error")
            results = None

    else:
        form_CourseForm = CourseForm()
        working_info = Working_Form()
    # handle situation when results is None (i.e. no inputs have been entered)

    if results is None:
        context['result'] = None

    else: #process output info
        context['num_results'] = len(results)

    context['form_CourseForm'] = form_CourseForm
    context['working_info'] = working_info
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**EDIT:**
After changing the method to POST from GET, I still face the same issue. I played around with the views.py code to manually set the args dictionary and found that regardless of the result of form_CourseForm.is_valid(), nothing is added to args, even when I make selections on both dropdown menus. This makes no sense to me, but it seems like form_CourseForm isn't functional at all?

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    res = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_CourseForm = CourseForm(request.POST)
        form_prof_fn = SearchForm_prof_fn(request.POST)
        form_prof_ln = SearchForm_prof_ln(request.POST)
        args = {}
        if form_CourseForm.is_valid():
            data = form_CourseForm.cleaned_data
            if data['dept']:
                args['dept'] = "Math" #doesn't work
            if data['course_num']:
                args['course_num'] = "100" #doesn't work
        else:
            args['dept'] = "History" #doesn't work
        args['rv'] = "123" #does work, so issue isn't with args itself
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/main.css" %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Website</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="frame">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="form_CourseForm">
                    {{ form_CourseForm }}
                </table>                                  
                <p>and/or</p>
                <table class="Working Form">
                    {{ working_form }}
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

        {% if args %}
        <div class="args">
            <pre>{{ args }}</pre>
        </div>
        {% endif %}

...code to print output table...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm... Normally forms are submitted with POST method and you have `if request.method == 'GET'` - did you mean `if request.method == 'POST'` by any chance?

Comment: you got to change the request type. the logic you have written needs to be in POST method, change them, and also the form method in the html page to POST instead of GET

Comment: What does your template look like? course_num and dept are both not required, so your form can be valid with both of those fields empty.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I just uploaded the relevant part of my html template. Yes that's true, however this issue is occurring even when I make selections for both dropdown menus.

Comment: Note you don't seem to be passing `args` back into the template, so it will never display.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Sorry for being unclear, but I actually do have args in my views.py, I just didn't include it for the sake of brevity. So I am able to display args and see what's in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    res = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_CourseForm = CourseForm(request.POST)
        working_info = Working_Form(request.POST)
        args = {}
        if form_CourseForm.is_valid():
            if request.POST['dept']:
                args['dept'] = request.POST['dept']
            if request.POST['course_num']:
                args['course_num'] = request.POST['course_num']
        if working_info.is_valid():
            ...

        if ('dept' in args) == ('course_num' in args): 
            try:
                results = process_inputs(args)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception caught')
        else:
            context['err'] = forms.ValidationError("Error")
            results = None
        return render(request,'template.html',{'args':args})
    else:
        form_CourseForm = CourseForm()
        working_info = Working_Form()
```

and also in html

```
<form method='post' action='' ...... >
```

Comment: I made these changes and it helped with the structure of the website but the problem still remains. I added additional context at the bottom of my question in the EDIT section.

Comment: you said the inputs are not saving right?? you are not saving them, thus its not saved, you have to write MyModel.objects.create() , to save to the database where you want to save @person10559

Comment: Sorry why do I need the .create() function? The problem right now is that views is not recognizing CourseForm's inputs for some reason, so user inputs are not recognized or stored. I don't need to save the inputs to my database, I just need to add them to the args dictionary to generate a table. I believe form_CourseForm = CourseForm(request.POST) should be storing the user inputs but it's not. I don't need to change the options in the dropdown menus, those lists should stay constant. @Exprator

Comment: have you tried to print(data) and check if you are getting anything or not

Comment: I have a method in my HTML template (that I just added to my question) that prints out the args dictionary, so yes I can see that there are no Departments or Course Numbers added to args even when I make selections on both dropdown menus.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no change in the results :(

Comment: change in results means? you cannot see the args in the template??

Comment: Nothing has changed. When I print out args on the website, there is still no "dept" or "course_num" values and there are no results returned (since args is incorrect).

Comment: you are not passing the args once the form is posted, check the edited ans

Comment: My code matches the most recent version of your comment and it still doesn't work. I'm not sure what you mean by "you are not passing the args once the form is posted"

Comment: i have added a line before the else part in your view, check it and add it

Comment: Ah gotcha, sorry about the misunderstanding. I couldn't run your line of code because it thew up some errors. I do have my own code in views.py to display args which I added to my original question. From my own testing, the args that are displayed on my website are correct. Also, I'm using args to build a sql query to build a graph and my graph code works with Working_Form, so the problem lies with CourseForm's inability to add arguments to args.